# vmware workstation 9 on ubuntu 12.04 network problems

Tags: 12.04, virtualization, vmware

I have been using vmware workstation 9 for about 3 months without any problems. A few days ago I started workstation and it prompted me that vmware had to compile modules and install them into the kernel. This has happened a few times before and there have never been any problems, but this time some module failed to compile/install.

Unfortunately I was too fast so I simply clicked "ok" which caused the dialog to close, and now i can't find any log file. Next time I stated workstation it simply started as normal, but now when I boot up my virtual machine (win7 pro 64 bit) I get the error: "Could not connect Ethernet0 to virtual network "/dev/vmnet8"".

So what I did was to check for updates (vmware updates) and found that I could download and install workstation 9.0.2, which I did. Now when I start my virtual machine I don't get the error message but now it reports the network cable as unplugged.

I have been searching for a solution for two days now and the only thing I can find is fixes for similar problems for workstation 8.

I don't know what information you need, but the basic info is:

- Thinkpad T430s
- 3.5.0-28-generic
- Workstation 9.0.2

Anyone have a clue of where I should start to look or what the problem might be?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried this but I got the following error:
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-28-generic/include/linux/version.h': File exists

Comment: Hi, I have looked a the link you posted and when I try to create any of the links it fails because those files already exists.

I also tried to run the "sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all --appname="VMware Player" --icon="vmware-player"" command which I guess recompiles and reinstalls all modules, but when it tries to start the services after its done I get:

Virtual ethernet                         failed

Comment: delete all comments...